# Cannot bind JSON to d3

Tags: json, d3.js, bind

I've search far and wide, but cannot bind JSON data to a simple scatterplot for the life of me. I've looked at posts and examples, but I can only manage to bind arrays and not JSON. Below, I've tried to simply display JSON data as text and still can't make it work. Please let me know if you have any idea why!

d3_attempt.js

```
var data;

d3.json("json_data.json",function(error, dataset) {
    if (error) return console.warn(error);

    data = dataset;

    var myscatter = d3.select("#somediv").append("svg")
                    .attr("width", 700)
                    .attr("height", 400);

    myscatter.selectAll("text")
        .data(data.data)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .text(function(d){return d)})
});
```

json_data.json

```
{
    "data":
    {
        "john": {"name": "john", "age": "13"},
        "matt": {"name": "matt", "age":"14"}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, you can only bind arrays, so you probably want to convert your data to an array:

```
myscatter.selectAll("text")
    .data(d3.values(data.data));
```

This will give each of your `text` nodes the `{ name, age }` object as data. If you need the keys too (looks like it's not required in this case), you could use `d3.entries`, which gives you an array of objects like `{ key: "john", value: { name: "John", age: "13" }}`.